# How to resume an HLS live stream from the point it was paused?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using AVPlayer to play a HLS live stream and I'm trying to force a delay by simulating a pause setting the player rate to 0.05, when the delay reaches the desired delay I set the rate to 1 and sometimes the player resets the stream. This can be observed more often on a simulator. Does anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the question asked in the headline/title of your question:

I use `player.pause()` and `player.play()` to pause and resume HLS feeds, and it works perfectly.  If you are programmatically determining the timing of your delay, you could try timing the `pause()` and `play()` methods.

Now, to address the question in the body:

I've occasionally observed this 'reset' behavior when trying to sync two devices manually (pause/play/pause/play).

My guess is that the player does its best to sync up to keyframes, depending on what it has buffered. Factors like the network connection's jitter or the stream's bit rate, keyframe rate, and frame rate will all play into how well the player recovers from state changes, and where it picks up in the stream.

When you're using the simulator, you're not benefitting from the performance gains of the actual hardware (since everything is emulated), so it's even more taxing on the CPU and more likely to be jumpy.